# Syntax error on token, 'Class', invalid type

Tags: java, class, syntax

The part with asterisks is what it shows error. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?
I already have a public class in the beginning.
If I take off the bracket "()", the code following that all shows errors.
Thanks!

```
    public class ButtonTester {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new adasdad();
}



//Setting up variables
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

private   JButton button = new JButton ("A");
private   JButton button2 = new JButton ("B");

 **class ExP12_4 () {**
    //Creating a frame
    //Creating a panel
    ...

    ...

    //Display frame
    ...

          }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the parenthesis and create a constructor for the class:

```
class ExP12_4 {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;

    public ExP12_4 (){
        button = new JButton ("A");
        button2 = new JButton ("B");

        frame = new JFrame ();
        panel = new JPanel ();

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel); 

        ...
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) for more info about Java Classes

Comment: Without the bracket,

The code following that almost all went wrong,

Comment: You have to change `new adasdad();` for `new ExP12_4();`, as you had it before editing the question. adasdad is not defined anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

There's no parenthesis allowed in a class definition. These belong in a constructor.
Also you need to put your statements in a code block such as the constructor or `init` method:

```
public class ExP12_4 {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;

    public ExP12_4() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry...I didn't include the full code... I already have a public class in the beginning...

Comment: No problem. In your `main` method you should be creating an outer class `ButtonTester` or make `ExP12_4` your outer class name and get rid of `ButtonTester` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `["a"]` instead of `("a")`.